# How to put on the index in the Key field of the IMap in Hazelcast 5.2.1

Tags: indexing, hazelcast

I am trying to query the Hazelcast map using predicates. I want to put an index on the key of my Hazelcast map.
Map Structure: IMap<Event, Long> - Event is a POJO class.
In the release of 3.12.12.
Exception: java. lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for ‘eventType’ on class ‘java.lang.Long’.

```
<indexes>
<index ordered=“true”>eventType</index>
</indexes>
```

From the exception I understand that Hazelcast is trying to apply the index on the Value field of the IMap.
I change the xml like this:

```
<indexes>
  <index ordered=“true”>__key#eventType</index>
</indexes>
```

It is ok. But When I upgrade to 5.2.1. I also want to the index can be put on the Key field of the IMap. How can I change the code?

```
 <indexes>
        <index>
             <attributes>
                <attribute>__key#eventType</attribute>
             </attributes>
        </index>
    </indexes>
```

Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for ‘__key#eventType’ on class ‘java.lang.Long’.
It seems it does not work of the __key#.Is there another way to write it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem, __key.eventType, that is ok